# Hide and show divs using PHP

Tags: php, hide, show, required

So I have this code that requires to be a member. Now the question is what code do I add to hide two different divs called "socialsignup" and "formwrap". Another question is can you have multiple `<?php code here ?>`s in different places on the same page? Much appreciated with any help.

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
$fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("login.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap multiple time of  PHP tags in a page.
That's answer for your fisrt and second question.
You can check like this

```
<?php if($val=='socialsignup') {?>
html for the social sign up  
<?php } else if ($val=='formwrap') {?>
html for formwrap
<?php }else{?>
remaining conditions
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: So in the remaining conditions area just add the php code I have or have that before everything?

Comment: You can add or leave the remaining conditions, I just demonstrate the if statement with html contents

Comment: Sorry in advance but I just don't really know php code at all. What exactly would the 'hide if user logged in' php code be?

Comment: you can check the loggedin user if(!$loggedinUser){ htmlcodehere }. This will display the html if the user is not logged in

Comment: So this should work then? <?php if(!loggedinUser){<section class="socialsignup">
<a href="#"><img src="images/signin-facebook.png"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/signin-twitter.png"></a>
<div id="form_wrap">
   <form id="contact-form" formaction="/webformmailer.php" method="POST" >

  <p id="formstatus"></p>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="username" placeholder=" Username" />
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="username" placeholder=" Password"  />
    <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Log In" />
   </form>

</div>
</section>
} ?>

Comment: on the part {html code here}..should I be wrapping the code in anything particular because when I do if(!$loggedinUser){<section class="socialsignup">html stuff here</section>}, it doesn't work? :/

Comment: you should close php tag before the html section. like, <?php if(!$loggedinUser){ ?> <section class="blabla">html stuff here</section><?php } ?>. the html element not belongs to php